# How to fix hover pseudo-class for IE9

Tags: css

I know this is a typical question but I cannot find the solution. My CSS drop down menu works fine everywhere but IE9. The drop down simply doesn't work in IE9. Any advice? Thank you.

Here is the menu HTML:

```
<div id="menu">
<ul> 
  <li><a href="#"><span>Needs Assessment</span></a>
    <ul> 
      <li><a href="#">History1</a></li> 
         <li><a href="#">Team1</a></li> 
         <li><a href="#">Offices1</a></li> 
    </ul> 
  </li>

  <li><a href="#"><span>Design and Development</span></a>
    <ul> 
         <li><a href="#">History2</a></li> 
     <li><a href="#">Team2</a></li> 
         <li><a href="#">Offices2</a></li> 
    </ul> 
  </li>

  <li><a href="#"><span>Prepare and Implement</span></a>
    <ul> 
         <li><a href="#">History3</a></li> 
         <li><a href="#">Team3</a></li> 
         <li><a href="#">Offices3</a></li> 
  </ul> 
 </li>

 <li><a href="#"><span>Debrief and Measure</span></a>
   <ul> 
        <li><a href="#">History4</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">Team4</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">Offices4</a></li> 
   </ul> 
</li>

<li><a href="#"><span>Resources</span></a>
  <ul> 
    <li><a href="#">History4</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">Team4</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">Offices4</a></li> 
  </ul> 
</li>

</ul>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS for this menu:

```
#menu {
    width: 942px;
    height: 47px;
    border: solid 0px #000;
}

#menu ul {
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}

#menu ul li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
}

#menu li ul {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    display: none;
}

#menu li:hover ul { 
    display: block;
    z-index: 999;
}

#menu li li a {
    color: #fff;
}

#menu li li a:hover {
    color: #ccc;
}

#menu ul li a {
    display: block;
    width: 188px;
    padding: 12px 0px 10px 0px;
    background:url 'http://www.laerdal.com/Laerdal/usa/discoversimulation/images/button.png');
    border: solid 0px black;
    font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
}

#menu a span {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    padding: 3px 5px 4px 6px;
    color:#fff;
    float: none;
    border: solid 0px black;
}

#menu a:hover span {
    color:#bbb;
}
```

Comment: The HTML would be easier to read with proper indentations.  Also, explain with detail exactly what _"doesn't work"_ means; after all, we can't see your page in action.

Comment: I am pretty sure IE9 handles the `:hover` pseudo-class just fine.

Comment: Better? This is a single-level dropdown menu. It works fine everywhere but IE9. When you hover over the menu, nothing drops down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Sparky672 said, your HTML is hopelessly invalid. You should fix it.

However, to fix the specific problem you're having, all you need to do is add a valid doctype as the very first line:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Without this, IE is in quirks mode.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't say hopeless, just a small oversight with the html with repeated tags in some pages. But the doctype fixed the problem.

Comment: @stevenpepe, thirtydot is 100% correct and I should have been more specific, although the missing `doctype` was the very first thing listed in the Validator report I linked to.  Now your errors are worse... the [Validator refuses to parse the page](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.laerdal.com/_LOCAL_CONTENT/usa/discoversimulation/debrief/&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) because you have some content _between_ the `</head>` and `<body>` where there should be nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing a demo, I have no idea if this will solve it, but you have a syntax error in your CSS.  Missing the opening `(`.

This way always works for me...

```
background-image: url(http://www.laerdal.com/Laerdal/usa/discoversimulation/images/button.png);
```

---

**Edited as per comments and [demo URL](http://laerdal.com/_LOCAL_CONTENT/usa/discoversimulation/debrief):**

You have some serious [HTML validation errors](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.laerdal.com/_LOCAL_CONTENT/usa/discoversimulation/debrief/&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).  *(Edit #2: Originally, the very first listed error was a missing `doctype` which will throw IE in quirks mode.)*

You have this in the top of your page...

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Debrief and Measure</title>
</head>

<body>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Discover Simulation</title>
</head>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> 
    <link href="/Laerdal/_LOCAL_CONTENT/usa/css/discoversimulation.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<body>
```

Notice all the duplicate `<html>`, `<body>` and `<head></head>` tags.

Then at the bottom of your page...

```
</body>
</html>

<div align="center">

    <div id="whitebox">

        ...snipped...

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Notice the extraneous `</body></html>` tags.

As an aside:  `align="center"` has been deprecated.

Comment: +1, syntactic errors are the real reason behind most of so called "browser bugs" ..

Comment: My actual code has the (. It didn't seem to copy over. Here is the link to view: http://www.laerdal.com/_LOCAL_CONTENT/usa/discoversimulation/debrief/

Comment: @stevenpepe, you have some serious HTML coding problems.  See my edited answer.